# wcf data service [webGet] method returning an int - how to read the int?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service [WebGet] method returning an int. (no of products in products table)

How can I read it's result?
The method works i checked with the browser.

```
     public void ProductsCount()
    {
        ctx.BeginExecute<int>(new Uri(uriBase + "/GetNoProducts"), GetProductsCountCompleted, ctx);
    }
    public void GetProductsCountCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        inventory_db_bigEntities context=result.AsyncState as inventory_db_bigEntities;
        var x = context.EndExecute<int>(result);

       //how do i read the int out of the x variable        
    }
```

UPDATE

Maybe BeginExecute and EndExecute is not the way to go for it.

In the browser window the webget method returns:

"<GetNoProducts p1:type="Edm.Int32">223863</GetNoProducts>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with your example? EndExecute should do the trick...just call FirstOrDefault() to get the primitive value. Alternatively, if you're not using SL, you can do it synchronously:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230677.aspx#ExecutePrimitiveValue

Comment: i was calling First() and getting an error. FirstOrDefault() works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) for `IAsyncResult` uses `BeginInvoke` rather than `BeginExecute` and then calls `EndInvoke` to get the value back:

```
// The asynchronous method puts the thread id here.
int threadId;

// Create an instance of the test class.
AsyncDemo ad = new AsyncDemo();

// Create the delegate.
AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(ad.TestMethod);

// Initiate the asychronous call.
IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, out threadId, null, null);

...

// Wait for the WaitHandle to become signaled.
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

// Perform additional processing here.
// Call EndInvoke to retrieve the results.
string returnValue = caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, result);
```